# svmclassify, class dimensions don't agree with samples dimensions

Tags: matlab, svm

I'm trying to apply SVM to my classification problem.
I have an issue with SVMClassify.

```
old_data=vi(5:10,:);
newData=vi(1,:);
svmStruct=svmtrain(old_data,groups(5:10),'Kernel_Function',@KFUN);
newClasses= svmclassify(svmStruvt, newData);
```

newClasses vector does'nt have same rows as newData matrix. I just can't understand why!

```
size_newClasses= size(newClasses);
```

returns  size_newClasses= 6 rows and 1 column. Any help please?

Comment: What result did you expect to get?

Comment: First of all, `svmStruvt` in your classify line should be `svmStruct`. Secondly, give us more information: what are the number of columns of `old_data`? What does `groups` do (seems to be something you wrote yourself)?

Comment: `groups` seems to be labeling vector. The size of the output should be 1 row and 1 column in case of one vector passed to the classifier, but as @Marc pointed out - there is a typo in the code, which may suggest that this is not really copied part of the code that produced this output, so the actual error may be located in the omitted parts